# When to use Lazy vs Func

Tags: c#

I have multiple boolean statements being evaluated. They are evaluated in order from top to bottom. Some boolean statements are expensive to evaluate so I am use lazy on them. Here is the sample code:

```
bool contactHasPermission = ContactHasPermission(id);
var contactIsInRole = new Lazy<bool>(() => IsContactInRole(contactId, roleType)); //Database call
var contactHasAtLeastXPoints = new Lazy<bool>(() => ContactHasXPoints(contactId, 100)); //database call

bool permit = contactHasPermission || contactIsInRole.Value || contactHasAtLeastXPoints.Value;
```

As you can see the most expensive statements are in lazy objects. I could have done the same thing using Func. What the the pros and cons of using one over the other?

Comment: Are you caching the `Lazy` instance for future use?

Comment: I don't think `Lazy` makes any sense here. `Lazy` is generally for when you're returning a large object you may or may not use. You're adding overhead. It's just a function call. Why would you use `Lazy` or `Func`? Just call `IsContactInRole` and `ContactHasXPoints` directly. Unless there is more related code you're not showing?

Comment: Do you need to use the expensive results more than once? Lazy caches the result while Funcs do not. Lazy also coordinates access between multiple threads attempting to construct the value.

Comment: The lazy is a database call. @Sean, I am not caching lazy

Comment: `bool permit = contactHasPermission || IsContactInRole(contactId, roleType) || ContactHasXPoints(contactId,100)`

Comment: @Lee no I do not need to access it more than once. I just need it one time in the situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither `Lazy` nor `Func` are magic. The only thing they provide is that you defer the execution of the code in question. It doesn't make it faster, it doesn't make it parallel, it just does it *later*.

The main benefit from using deferred execution comes when you can *avoid* the execution entirely in some cases. For example, if you have a piece of code like this:

```
a() && b() && c()
```

you know that it only makes sense to evaluate `b()` and `c()` when `a()` returns true. The deferred execution of `b()` and `c()` never happens. You lose this property when you store the intermediate results in locals (for example, to improve readability):

```
var resultOfA = a();
var resultOfB = b();
var resultOfC = c();

...

return resultOfA && resultOfB && resultOfC;
```

There's no longer any opportunity to defer the execution of `b()`, unless you use horrible code like `var resultOfB = resultOfA && b();`. However, you can also inline the function to be evaluated, rather than the *result* of the function to be evaluated.

The simplest way to do this in C# is using a function delegate:

```
Func<bool> fa = () => a();
Func<bool> fb = () => b();
Func<bool> fc = () => c();

...

return fa() && fb() && fc();
```

However, this means that whenever you execute `fa`, for example, you evaluate `a()` again and again. That might be desired or not. If it's not desired, you come to the world of `Lazy`.

`Lazy` allows you to defer execution, but cache the result of the execution so that any subsequent accesses to the lazy object will just use the result of the original deferred execution, rather than evaluating the "constructor" function again.

So, in summary:

1. You can use short-circuiting to avoid execution of expressions in a boolean expression.
2. You can use `Func` to defer the execution (and possibly avoid it) no matter the context, so you can easily compose complex short-circuiting patterns.
3. You can use `Lazy` to defer the execution (and possibly avoid it), while also caching the result for any subsequent evaluations of the lazy's value. This is particularly useful for long-lived objects with non-trivial scope.

In your sample code, the best choice is probably 1) - no point in getting the overhead of function delegates, when you can use short-circuiting. The main benefit of deferred  execution here is to allow you to *name* parts of the expression - so that you get e.g. `hasPermission() && isInRole() && isSunny()` instead of a hard to read expression. If you only use each part of the expression at most once, there's no point in using `Lazy` - it just means extra boilerplate around the underlying `Func`.

Answer (score 5):

If you use your boolean condition only once - there seems to be no considerable difference between Lazy and Func in your case. However if you do use them more than once then of course Lazy is preferrable - it will actually compute value just once and will return cached value on next calls.

Note that because boolean conditions are already lazily evaluated, you can just do:

```
bool permit = contactHasPermission || IsContactInRole(contactId, roleType) || ContactHasXPoints(contactId, 100)
```

and if will have the same effect - expensive calls will not be evaluated unless necessary. However if you want to do that for *readability*, and you don't reuse your boolean conditions - use Func.

Answer (score 4):

In your particular scenario, neither `Func` nor `Lazy` make sense here. C# short-circuits evaluations, so

```
bool permit = contactHasPermission || 
  IsContactInRole(contactId, roleType) || 
  ContactHasXPoints(contactId, 100);
```

will do just fine: if `contactHasPermission` is `true`, no database calls will be made.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but yet not answered correctly. So here goes.

Check exampel on this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IhzncU).

You use Lazy to create instance of an object at a later point when it is needed, however once invoked, it holds that instance of the object in the Value property. There is no way to change this instance.

Similarly Func defer creating instance of the object, however each time you invoke the Func you will get a new instance of the object.

So you use Lazy where you need only one deferred instance of the object and use Func where you want to create new instance of the object on each invoke.

In your case, if you have to re-evaluate the condition each time, you should use Func, however if you want to evaluate the condition only once and use the result many times, you can use Lazy.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are caching the `Lazy` instances as member variables then there is a performance improvement as you can delay the evaluation. However, if you're not then there's nothing to be gained. You might as well say:

```
bool permit = ContactHasPermission(id) || 
              IsContactInRole(contactId, roleType) ||
              ContactHasXPoints(contactId, 100);
```

The short-circuit evaluation of `||` will ensure that you'll only evaluate the minimum you need to, and thus avoid subsequent expensive calls.